# Is it correct:$\lambda_{\min}(A) \langle I,B\rangle \le \langle A,B \rangle \le \lambda_{\max}(A) \langle I,B\rangle$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, semidefinite-programming

Assume that $A$ is a semi-definite matrix and $B$ is not. Also $\langle,\rangle$ is the standard inner product on the semi-definite cone. $\lambda_{\min}$ and $\lambda_{\max}$ are minimum and maximum eigen value of the matrix repectively.

Is the following inequality is correct? if it's not what is the weakest condition that it is correct?

$$\lambda_{\min}(A) \langle I,B\rangle \le \langle A,B \rangle \le \lambda_{\max}(A) \langle I,B\rangle$$

It is well known that if $B$ is positive semidefinite it's true, but I want the weakest condition on $B$. Based on the comment and an answer, it is not true for the general $B$, also it's true for the semidefinte $B$. Is the weakest condition is semidefiniteness of $B$. If it is, isn't any other upper/lower bound for this quantity based on eigen values of $A, B$?

Comment: How did you go about showing or proving that this conjecture is correct? Or are you claiming that you believe it is correct, and asking one of us to prove it for you?

Comment: It is true if $B$ is positive semidefinite. Otherwise, it is wrong

Comment: take $B = \operatorname{diag}(1, -1)$ and for the first inequality $A=\operatorname{diag}(1/2, 1)$, for the second inequality $A=\operatorname{diag}(1, 1/2)$

Comment: Now I am asking the weakest condition on $B$ that it is true? or hopefully an upper bound or lower bound on the quantity based on eigen value of $A$ and/or $B$

Comment: The weakest condition for an inequality to hold is the inequality itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inequality always holds in the scalar case. So, we may consider only matrices whose sizes are at least $2\times2$. Also, as both $A$ and $I$ are Hermitian, the skew-Hermitian part of $B$ is irrelevant in the inner products. Hence we may assume that $B$ is Hermitian. Now, we claim that:

> Let $B$ be a Hermitian matrix of size at least $2\times2$. Then $\lambda_{\min}(A) \langle I,B\rangle \le \langle A,B \rangle \le \lambda_{\max}(A) \langle I,B\rangle$ for every semidefinite $A$ if and only if $B$ is positive semidefinite.

**Proof.** If $B$ is positive semidefinite, by a change of orthonormal basis, we may assume that $A$ is diagonal and the inequality follows immediately.

If $B$ is not positive semidefinite, let $u$ be a unit eigenvector corresponding to a negative eigenvalue $-\lambda$ of $B$ and let $A=uu^\ast$. Then $\lambda_\min(A)=0$ and hence $\lambda_\min(A)\langle I,B\rangle=0>-\lambda = \langle A,B \rangle$.

Answer (score 0):

As the earlier comment states, this *does not* hold for arbitrary matrices $B$.  However, the statement holds if $B$ is positive semidefinite.

In order to prove that the inequality holds for positive semidefinite $A,B$, it suffices to note that $A - \lambda_{min}I$ and $\lambda_{max}I-A$ are both positive semidefinite, and that $\langle M,N\rangle \geq 0$ for any $M,N$ in the semidefinite cone.

Comment: I know that it is true for positive semidefinte $B$, but is it the weakest condition? I mean there is not a lowerbound or upper bound for $\langle A,B\rangle$ based on the eigen value of $A$ and/or $B$?